# MySQL Index on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have a select query where I need to include following columns(almost all the columns from the table):

```
SELECT  ANI,CALL_ID, DATE_TIME, ABANDON_RATE, CALL_TYPE, CAMPAIGN, CAMPAIGN_TYPE, CUSTOMER_NAME, DISPOSITION, DNIS, LIST_NAME, 
        SESSION_ID, SKILL, AGENT_EMAIL, AGENT_GROUP, THIRD_PARTY_TALK_TIME, AFTER_CALL_WORK_TIME, HOLD_TIME, CALL_TIME, HANDLE_TIME, IVR_TIME,
        MANUAL_TIME, TALK_TIME, QUEUE_WAIT_TIME, advertiserName, affiliateName, callerID, campaignName, ChargentSFA__Biling_Phone__c, CONTACT_CREATE_TIMESTAMP,
        CONTACT_ID, CONTACT_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP, Date_Added, destinationPhoneNumber, leadsource, number1, salesforce_id, source, transactionID,
        IVR_PATH 
FROM call_data_report 
WHERE ANI= '123456' OR DNIS = '123456' 
ORDER BY DATE_TIME desc;
```

This query takes too much time to execute(more than 3 mins). In order to improve the query performance I have created an index on the columns used in the where clause i.e. ANI and DNIS.

```
create index ani_idx on call_data_report(ANI,DNIS)
```

But, when I checked the output of EXPLAIN for above select query it is showing me that it is not using index. Is it becuase of all these columns? What type of index do I need to create to improve the performance of above query.

Note: ANI and DNIS having NULL values in the columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A composite index is only useful when you're combining the tests with `AND`, not `OR`. When you have an `OR` condition, it has to test each column independently, but a composite index is a tree that has all the values of `DNIS` within their related `ANI`. So you should create separate indexes for each column.

MySQL also isn't generally good at optimizing `OR` queries. It would probably be better if you split it into two queries that you combine with `UNION`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM call_data_report
WHERE ANI = 123456
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM call_data_report
WHERE DNIS = 123456
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar, Thank you for the information regarding the query optimization. I have created two separate indexes on ANI and DNIS. But when I execute the EXPLAIN SELECT ... FROM call_data_report WHERE ANI=12345 it is giving me the following output.

id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | keys | key_len | ref | rows | Extra =>

1 | SIMPLE | call_data_report | ALL | ani_idx | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2995289|Using where

Does this mean it is still not using index?

Comment: That's what it means. I don't know why it's not using the index.

Comment: whether there will be any issue if these two fields are varchar type?

Comment: If it's varchar, try quoting the value: `WHERE ANI = '12345'`

Comment: I think I missed the quote part. Thank you. Explain output is indicating that it is using index now.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could try using two single column index ..

```
create index ani_idx1 on call_data_report(ANI);

create index ani_idx2 on call_data_report(DNIS);
```

because usinge OR the second key of your composite  index ani_idx `DNIS` is not used  ..